# Why does changing into a subdirectory affect the output of `git status`?

Tags: git

Initial output:

```
ravi@boxy ~/.dotfiles/.vim/bundle $ git status
On branch master
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.
nothing to commit, working directory clean
ravi@boxy ~/.dotfiles/.vim/bundle $
```

And now cd and run git status again:

```
ravi@boxy ~/.dotfiles/.vim/bundle $ cd neobundle.vim/
ravi@boxy ~/.dotfiles/.vim/bundle/neobundle.vim $ git status
On branch master
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

    modified:   .gitignore
    modified:   .travis.yml
    modified:   LICENSE-MIT.txt
    modified:   Makefile
    modified:   README.md
    modified:   autoload/neobundle.vim
    modified:   autoload/neobundle/TOML.vim
    modified:   autoload/neobundle/autoload.vim
    modified:   autoload/neobundle/cache.vim
    modified:   autoload/neobundle/commands.vim
    modified:   autoload/neobundle/config.vim
    modified:   autoload/neobundle/init.vim
    modified:   autoload/neobundle/installer.vim
    modified:   autoload/neobundle/parser.vim
    modified:   autoload/neobundle/sources/github.vim
    modified:   autoload/neobundle/sources/neobundle_vim_recipes.vim
    modified:   autoload/neobundle/types/git.vim
    modified:   autoload/neobundle/types/hg.vim
    modified:   autoload/neobundle/types/nosync.vim
    modified:   autoload/neobundle/types/raw.vim
    modified:   autoload/neobundle/types/svn.vim
    modified:   autoload/neobundle/types/vba.vim
    modified:   autoload/neobundle/util.vim
    modified:   autoload/neobundle/vamkr.vim
    modified:   autoload/unite/kinds/neobundle.vim
    modified:   autoload/unite/sources/neobundle.vim
    modified:   autoload/unite/sources/neobundle_install.vim
    modified:   autoload/unite/sources/neobundle_lazy.vim
    modified:   autoload/unite/sources/neobundle_log.vim
    modified:   autoload/unite/sources/neobundle_search.vim
    modified:   bin/install.sh
    modified:   bin/neoinstall
    modified:   bin/neoinstall.bat
    modified:   bin/neoinstall_novimproc.bat
    modified:   ftdetect/vimrecipe.vim
    modified:   plugin/neobundle.vim
    modified:   syntax/vimrecipe.vim
    modified:   test/commands.vim
    modified:   test/lock.vim
    modified:   test/parse.vim
    modified:   test/recipe.vim
    modified:   test/sample.vim
    modified:   test/source.vim
    modified:   test/toml.vim
    modified:   test/tsort.vim

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
ravi@boxy ~/.dotfiles/.vim/bundle/neobundle.vim $
```

Why wasn't this longer listing included in the `git status` of the parent directory?

Main `.gitignore`:

```
ravi@boxy ~/.dotfiles $ cat .gitignore 
# Don't put a comment after a command!

*~
*.swp

.vim/.netrwhist
.vim/ctrlp-cache/

# 
# Include neobundle to bootstrap
# 
# entries but not the dir itself
.vim/bundle/*
# include directory only
!.vim/bundle/

!.vim/bundle/neobundle.vim/
ravi@boxy ~/.dotfiles $
```

Subdirectory `.gitignore`

```
ravi@boxy ~/.dotfiles/.vim/bundle/neobundle.vim $ cat .gitignore 
doc/tags
ravi@boxy ~/.dotfiles/.vim/bundle/neobundle.vim $
```

Version:

```
ravi@boxy ~/.dotfiles $ git --version
git version 2.6.3
ravi@boxy ~/.dotfiles $
```

Comment: Do you have a `.git/` directory in both `~/.dotfiles/.vim/bundle` and `~/.dotfiles/.vim/bundle/neobundle.vim`?

Comment: Because `neobundle.vim` is a separate repository.

Comment: Yes, they're two different repositories. Is there any way of updating sub-repositories at the same time as a the containing one is updated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`/.dotfiles/.vim/bundle/neobundle.vim` is a repository so any changes therein are hidden from the containing repository.

However, the included repo was *not* added as a submodule, so it wouldn't be brought down with a `git clone` as would be desirable for a .dotfiles setup.

## submodule-ise

1. Remove files from submodule which somehow got tracked in parent repo:

   `git rm --cache -r neobundle.vim/`
2. Add it as a submodule

   `git submodule add https://github.com/Shougo/neobundle.vim .vim/bundle/neobundle.vim/`
3. Initialise and update

   ```
   git submodule init
   git submodule update
   ```

## Update all submodules

```
git submodule update --recursive
```

## Reference

A great guide on [Git Submodules: Adding, Using, Removing, Updating](https://chrisjean.com/git-submodules-adding-using-removing-and-updating/) which isn't fully supported with the `git submodule ...` commands.

Thanks to Nicolas for pointing me in the right direction, especially the mention of "submodule".

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are using a Vim package manager, it seems like you have Git sumodules in your repository.

As a result, `~/.dotfiles/.vim/bundle/neobundle.vim` is another Git repository, which has its own status. Normally you would see that this submodule has changed in the parent repository (`~/.dotfiles/.vim/bundle`), but the directory it's in might have been ignored. Additionally, won't see those files in the parent directory's status because they are owned by the submodule, not the repository itself.

Comment: You said: "but the directory it's in might have been ignored" however I'm explicitly excluding it from being ignored as shown above:
`!.vim/bundle/neobundle.vim/`

So why don't I see it then?